# SQL: aggregate sizes into bins

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have a (Sybase) table that has the following information:

```
 order_id   int   
 timestamp  datetime   
 action     char(1)      --i=inserted, c=corrected, r=removed   
 shares      int
```

It keeps track of the shares associated with an order (identified by its order_id) in a system.
Using an example, the life of an order is as follows:

```
  timestamp action  shares      
  10:00:00  i       1000     -- initial Insert    
  10:06:30  c       900      -- one Change    
  10:07:12  c       800    
  10:50:20  r       800      -- Removal    
  11:10:10  i       600      -- 2nd Insert    
  11:12:10  r       600
```

In the example above, the order is active from 10:00:00 and 10:50:20, and again from 11:10:10 and 11:12:10

I have 1000s of such orders in the system and I need to plot with a histogram how many shares are active in a time series divided into bins/buckets of 5 minutes.
If the number of shares for a given order changes more than once within the samenter code heree bin, I need to average the shares; as in the example above in the 10:05-10:10 bin where 1000, 900 and 800 can be avg'd out as 900.

Here's a more complex example:

```
1, "20140828 10:00:00",  "i", 1000
1, "20140828 10:06:00",  "c",  900
1, "20140828 10:07:12",  "c",  500
1, "20140828 10:10:10",  "c",  400
1, "20140828 10:20:20",  "r",  400
1, "20140828 10:30:10",  "i",  300
1, "20140828 10:32:10",  "r",  300

2, "20140828 09:51:00",  "i",  500
2, "20140828 10:08:30",  "r",  500

3, "20140828 10:10:00",  "i", 1000
3, "20140828 10:11:20",  "r", 1000
```

with its expected output:

```
10:00:00 1500
10:05:00 1300
10:10:00 1450
10:15:00 400
10:20:00 400
10:25:00 0
10:30:00 300
10:35:00 0
10:40:00 0
10:45:00 0
10:50:00 0
10:55:00 0
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post your expecting output result of your example input data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @JaugarChang. I changed my posting a bit and added a more comprehensive example and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on the [*Running Sum* problem in SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) (either MS or Sybase, due to shared history),  grouped by the bucket ID, which can simply be the time difference in minutes from a base time *integer-divided* by 5. So something like this will do:

```
create table #t(
    BucketNo    int not null primary key clustered,
    Activity    int not null,
    Active      int not null
);

-- pre-aggregate activity data
-- assumes prior existence of a zero-based NUMBERS or TALLY table
insert #t(BucketNo,Activity,Active) 
select 
     N
    ,isnull(Activity,0)
    ,0
from NUMBERS 
left join (
    select
         datediff(mm,0,TimeStamp) / 5 as BucketNo
        ,case action when 'i' then +1
                          'r' then -1
         end * shares          as Activity
        ,0 as Active  
    from  ActivityTable
    where action <> 'c'
    group by            datediff(mm,0,TimeStamp) / 5 

    union all

    select
         datediff(mm,0,TimeStamp) / 5 as BucketNo
        ,case action when 'i' then +1
                          'r' then -1
         end * shares
         - (  select top 1 i.shares 
              from ActivityTable i
              where i.order_id = c.order_id  and  i.TimeStamp > c.TimeStamp
              order by i.TimeStamp desc
           ) as Activity
        ,0 as Active  
    from ActivityTable as c
    where c.action  = 'c         
    group by            datediff(mm,0,TimeStamp) / 5 
) data on data.BucketNo = N
where N < 24 * 12; -- 5 minute buckets per day
```

Now we use the SQL Server *quirky update* to process #t in clustered-index order to perform the Running Sum.

```
declare @Shares   int = 0,
        @BucketNo int = 0;

-- `quirky update` peculiar to SQL Server
update #t
   set @Shares = Shares 
               = case when BucketNo = @BucketNo
                      then @Shares + Activity
                      else 0
                 end,
       @BucketNo = BucketNo
from #t with (TABLOCKX) -- not strictly necessary when using a temp table.
option (MAXDOP 1);      -- prevent parallelization of query

select BucketNo, Active from #t order by BucketNo
go
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I'm trying your solution (with some modification for Sybase) but I have 3 questions: 1) what's that NUMBERS/TALLY table that you are talking about, 2) I'm getting a syntax error that I can't resolve around the `select top 1 i.shares` line: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 181`, 3) will the quirky update work in Sybase?

Comment: @jeromeso: **Numbers table**: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable and http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/you-require-a-numbers-table.aspx. Yes, quirky update should still work in SYBASE, as it pre-dates the separation of SYBASE and MS flavours of SQL Server. re the syntax error, try **FIRST** instead of **TOP 1** (as per http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315771.htm)

Comment: After playing with the SQL solution I realized that it was slower than my Perl implementation and so I continued with Perl. Thanks for the suggestion, @PieterGeedkens! I learn quite a bit.